# When Nameservers are mapped, my domain say 404 Not Found

Tags: http-status-code-404

Hello I have a domain in godaddy, and the server in digital ocean.
In godaddy I configured the nameservers like this: ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com

when I enter the domain in the control panel (plesk), I see that there is an error in the DNS configuration, and it says "The domain name of the website does not resolve or resolves to a different IP address". and when I enter the domain it shows me 404 not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Plesk control panel? It is not correct. You may login to your domain portal registration to change your name server. If you are not sure, you can contact Godaddy and ask them to point your domain to DigitalOcean name server.